# NodeJs insert current Datetime field into MySQL db

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm trying to insert a DATETIME field into my MySQL db.

```
var dt = require('moment')().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    pool.query(
      `insert into login(id, id_utente, data_login) values(NULL,?,?)`,
      [results[0].id],
      [dt],
      (error, results, fields) => {
      }
    );
```

I get this error:

```
C:\Users\tiger\Desktop\prova\REST_API_WITH_MYSQL-master\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
  throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
  ^TypeError: this._callback.apply is not a function
```

If I try this code, everything comes right:

```
pool.query(
      `insert into login(id, id_utente, data_login) values(NULL,?,"2021-01-27 00:00:00")`,
      [results[0].id],
      //[dt],
      (error, results, fields) => {
      }
    );
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your parameters in 2 separate arrays. Put your parameters in the same parameter array.

```
 pool.query(
  `insert into login(id, id_utente, data_login) values(NULL,?,?)`,
  [results[0].id, dt],
  (error, results, fields) => {
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct format probably is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS(I think it depends on MySQL configuration, but this is the default) as the docs points out.
So you should try using moment's format() method like this:

```
const myDate =  moment(data.myTime.format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss')).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");

pool.query(
  `insert into login(id, id_utente, data_login) values(NULL,?,?)`,
  [results[0].id, myDate],
  (error, results, fields) => {
  }
);
```